# Explode String and convert it into time PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a string "Monday, April 28, 6:00pm - 11:00pm."  I want to parse it into individual variables so I can format it and then convert it into UTC.  Also, I only want the first part of the time.  I figured a way to do it would be to explode it....

```
$arrayString = explode(',', $string);  //split string my comma
$startTime = explode(' - ', $arrayString[2]); //split time by using -
$times = $startTime[0];  
$date = strtotime($times);
echo date('g:ia', $date);  //Getting time
```

I want to output 06:00 pm (so I can test if $date works later for converting time to UTC).  Yet I get 1:00am.  When I try to do the same for Month, it gives me January.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: for a start, your sting has no comma

Comment: oops. fixed.  The original string was "Monday, April 28, 6:00pm - 11:00pm"

Comment: you can keep monday strtotime is smart, and i get 6pm as expected: http://codepad.viper-7.com/4FFn7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating $date only with reference to the time part of your string, hence it will default to January.

If you concatenate $arraystring[1] with your $times variable then you will probably get there.

Suggest you look at the DateTime class for your result variable as it will make time zone conversion easier.